# How to drag widgets from monitor to monitor in kubuntu?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kubuntu, widgets

I have Kubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron. I use an extern monitor as my default one, and my laptop monitor as my second monitor.

I can place widgets on the extern (default) screen, but when I drag them to the laptop (second) screen, they disappear. I can put widgets on the second screen, if I open the widget menu on that screen, but I can't drag them to my first monitor.

How can I switch between monitors for the widgets?

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around. Make an empty panel. Put the widgets in it. Then you can move the panel to the bottom screen.

Comment: While this isn't a bad idea, my question isn't answered. Should I be able to drag the panel itself across monitors? Because that's not working here.

Comment: I can. Just get them to the mode where you usually move them, and then go to the other screen.